# Set value to input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add some value in an input field with jQuery. The problem is with the ID of the input field. I am using the id such as `options[input2]`. In that case my code does not work. If I use ID like `input2`, then it works fine. I need to use `options[input2]`, how can I fix the code?

**HTML:**

```html
<div>
    <h3>Working</h3>
    <input id="input1" type="text" value="" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="Add value" />
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Not working</h3>
    <input id="options[input2]" type="text" value="" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="Add value" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
    var fieldID = $(this).prev().attr("id");
    $('#' + fieldID).val("hello world");
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4XR8M/

Comment: [] characters are not valid in html [id](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id) property

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it as below.

```
$(this).prev('input').val("hello world");
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4XR8M/2/)

Comment: This is not really working anymore, try clicking on live demo, it just replace the input rather than adding value to the input

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use

```
 $(this).prev().val("hello world");
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3rrTh/)

Comment: This is not really working anymore, try clicking on live demo, it just replace the input rather than adding value to the input

Comment: @faize, Just checked fiddle. It's working as expected. Can you share more information?

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape `[` and `]`.
Try this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var fieldID = $(this).prev().attr("id");
    fieldID = fieldID.replace(/([\[\]]+)/g, "\\$1");
    $('#' + fieldID).val("hello world");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7RJtf/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(obj, function(index, value) {
    $('#looking_for_job_titles').tagsinput('add', value);
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use
**$(this).prev().val("hello world");**

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#10").click(function(){
    $("input:text").val("10");
  });
  $("#20").click(function(){
    $("input:text").val("20");
  });
  $("#30").click(function(){
    $("input:text").val("30");
  });
  $("#40").click(function(){
    $("input:text").val("40");
  });
  $("#50").click(function(){
    $("input:text").val("50");
  });
  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="user"></p>

<button id="10">Apply Discount 10%</button><br>
<button id="20">Apply Discount 20%</button><br>
<button id="30">Apply Discount 30%</button><br>
<button id="40">Apply Discount 40%</button><br>
<button id="50">Apply Discount 50%</button><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).