# How to add value to an input rather than replacing the input with new value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the current input `id` and storing it in a variable and selecting that input to add whatever the previous `input` value that was entered by the user.

```
$("#" + current_cursor_input).prev().val("value added");
```

However the `prev()` function does not really add a new value, it just replaces the old one, same as how the code below works

```
 $("#" + current_cursor_input).val("value added");
```

I have seen previous StackOverflow answers and the answers no longer work, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655295/adding-value-to-input-field-with-jquery/18655344)

Comment: Are you trying to add a numeric value to the existing one? Your question is not clear. `prev()` is completely unrelated to amending a value, which is just making it even more confusing

Comment: I am trying to add value to the input , say if the user has typed something on the input box and on a key press event i'm adding/concatenating more texts to it based on the key pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can provide a function to `val()` which accepts the current value as an argument. You can then concatenate it with the new value you want to add on, something like this:

```
$("#" + current_cursor_input).val((i, v) => v + " value added");
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the previous value, then add to it:

```
var previousValue = $("#" + current_cursor_input).val();
$("#" + current_cursor_input).val(previousValue + "value added");
```